# Problem with compiz saving key bindings

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, keyboard, settings, shortcuts

I use Blender on Ubuntu, and need to free a shortcut. The key combination is Ctrl+Alt+Numpad0. In CCSM this shortcut is listed under general settings > Keybindings. But when i edit this setting, nothing changes. And when i restart CCSM they old key combination is back. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried Keyboard Shortcuts under system settings?

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/528517/46437, may work

Answer (score 0):

CCSM forces certain shortcuts after reboot.

If you uninstall CCSM you can permanently set shortcuts with System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts.