# CCSM not saving any changes made

Tags: unity, shortcuts, ccsm

I'm making changes with ccsm to the unity plugin, mainly to disable a whole ton of useless keyboard shortcuts which just take fullscreen applications out of focus and cause other problems.
The changes however, are all being undone every reboot and when I run ccsm again, all the changes are showing as there, but all the shortcuts become re-enabled.  I then have to restore each one to default again, and re-disable it, only to have it happen on the next reboot.
How do I get it to save the changes and actually, save the changes instead of just showing them saved?

Comment: hehe, try this `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-backend-gconf`, I am just trying it; I will only know if it worked after boot tho... http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2133125

Comment: it did not work here... wonder if work for someone else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz_Configuration

You will know about this file:
`~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/Default.ini`

Also you will have to opt for the "Flat-file configuration backend" for the below to work.

**So, to FORCE your settings you can do this:**
First of all: backup your `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/Default.ini`
Now, simply put ccsm at startup applications, it will ensure applying Default.ini configurations, as otherwise that file may still be ignored.

**If that still doesnt work, you can try this also:**
Open your ccsm, go in **Preferences/Profile/Export**, so you can save your preferences.
Now, copy your preferences to `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/`.
Still there, ***backup the Default.ini*** file.
Now rename your preferences file to Default.ini.

My changes finally persisted after boot!